# Laravel - How to handle Undefined Offset: 1

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a Laravel-5.8 project. I am using dynamic input field as shown below:

StoreAppraisalGoalRequest

```
class StoreAppraisalGoalRequest extends FormRequest
{
public function authorize()
{
    return \Gate::allows('appraisal_goal_create');
}
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'goal_title'                => 'required|min:5|max:100|unique:appraisal_goals,goal_title,goal_type_id,appraisal_identity_id,employee_id',   
        'goal_type_id'              => 'required',
        'weighted_score'            => 'required|numeric|min:0|max:500',

        'start_date'                => 'required',
        'end_date'                  => 'required|after_or_equal:start_date',
        'appraisal_goal_id'         => 'required',
        'kpi_description'           => 'required|max:300',
        'activity'                  => 'required|max:300',
    ];
  }
}
```

Models

AppraisalGoal

```
    protected $fillable = [
              'goal_type_id',
              'appraisal_identity_id',
              'employee_id',
              'company_id',
              'is_published',
              'is_approved',
              'weighted_score',
              'employee_comment',
              'line_manager_comment',
              'goal_title',
              'start_date',
              'end_date',
              'created_by',
              'created_at',
              'updated_by',
              'updated_at',
              'is_active'
          ];
```

AppraisalGoalDetail

```
    protected $fillable = [
              'name',
              'company_id',
              'appraisal_goal_id',
              'kpi_description',
              'appraisal_doc',
              'activity',
              'created_by',
              'created_at',
              'updated_by',
              'updated_at',
              'is_active'
          ];
```

Controller

```
public function create()
{
  $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
  $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('appraisal_name')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();  
  $goaltypes   =       AppraisalGoalType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get(); 
 $categories = AppraisalGoalType::with('children')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->whereNull('parent_id')->get();

return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.create')
        ->with('goaltypes', $goaltypes)
        ->with('categories', $categories)
        ->with('identities', $identities);
}

public function store(StoreAppraisalGoalRequest $request)
{
  $startDate = Carbon::parse($request->start_date);
  $endDate = Carbon::parse($request->end_date);
  $appraisal_identity_id = AppraisalIdentity::where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current',1)->value('id');
  try {
    $goal = new AppraisalGoal();
    $goal->goal_type_id             = $request->goal_type_id;
    $goal->appraisal_identity_id    = $appraisal_identity_id;
    $goal->employee_id              = $request->employee_id;
    $goal->weighted_score           = $request->weighted_score;
    $goal->goal_description         = $request->goal_description;
    $goal->start_date               = $startDate;
    $goal->end_date                 = $endDate;
    $goal->company_id               = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $goal->created_by               = Auth::user()->id;
    $goal->created_at               = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $goal->is_active                = 1;
    $goal->save();

    foreach ( $request->activity as $key => $activity){
        $goaldetail = new AppraisalGoalDetail();
        $goaldetail->kpi_description            = $request->kpi_description [$key];
        $goaldetail->appraisal_doc              = $request->appraisal_doc [$key];
        $goaldetail->activity                   = $request->activity[$key];
        $goaldetail->appraisal_goal_id          = $goal->id;
        $goaldetail->company_id                 = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $goaldetail->created_by                 = Auth::user()->id;
        $goaldetail->created_at                 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $goaldetail->is_active                  = 1;
        $goaldetail->save();
     }
        Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Goal is created successfully');
        return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index');
  } catch (Exception $exception) {
        Session::flash('danger', 'Appraisal Goal creation failed!');
        return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index');
  }
}
```

view

```html
 <form  action="{{route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {{csrf_field()}}
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">
            
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Goal Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <select id="goal_type" class="form-control" name="goal_type_id">
                <option value="">Select Goal Type</option>

                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                @unless($category->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
                  <option disabled="disabled" value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>

                  @if ($category->children)
                    @foreach ($category->children as $child)
                    @unless($child->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
                      <option value="{{ $child->id }}" {{ $child->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $child->name }}</option>
                    @endunless
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                  @endunless
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>    
            
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Goal Title:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input  type="text" name="goal_title" placeholder="Enter goal title here" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
            
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Goal Description</label>
                <textarea rows="2" name="goal_description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Goal Description here ..."></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

 <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Activity<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col">KPI Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col">Attachment</th>
                            <th scope="col"><a class="addRow"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="activity[]" class="form-control activity" ></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="kpi_description[]" class="form-control kpi" ></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                <input type="file" name="appraisal_doc[]" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
                         </tr>
                        </tbody>


                    </table>
        </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Weight:</label>
              <input  type="number" name="weighted_score" placeholder="Enter weighted score here" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>  

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Start Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="start_date"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> End Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="end_date"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
            </div>
          </div>

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>           
       
 </form>
```

javascript

```html
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.addRow').on('click', function () {
   var isHod = {{ Auth::user()->is_hod == 0 ? 0 : 1 }};
    var numRows = $('.activity').length

    if (isHod || (!isHod && numRows<2)) {
        addRow();
    }
        });

        function addRow() {
            var addRow = '<tr>\n' +
'  <td><input type="text" name="activity[]" class="form-control activity" ></td>\n' +
'  <td><input type="text" name="kpi_description[]" class="form-control kpi_description" ></td>\n' +
'  <td><div class="custom-file"><input type="file" name="appraisal_doc[]" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile"><label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label></div></td>\n' +
'  <td><a   class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>\n' +
'  </tr>';
            $('tbody').append(addRow);
            addRemoveListener();
        };
    addRemoveListener();
});

function addRemoveListener() {
$('.remove').on('click', function () {
        var l =$('tbody tr').length;
        if(l==1){
            alert('you cant delete last one')
        }else{

            $(this).parent().parent().remove();

        }

    });
}

</script>
```

When I clicked on save, I got this error

> Undefined offset: 1

I also found this highlighted: :\xampp\htdocs\peopleedge\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidatesAttributes.php return $last; }

```
return $attribute;
}
protected function getExtraConditions(array $segments)
{
  $extra = [];

$count = count($segments);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 2) {
    $extra[$segments[$i]] = $segments[$i + 1];
}

  return $extra;
}
```

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: @Aksen - No. It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, [it can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/11607574)

Comment: How will that resolve it?

Comment: put `StoreAppraisalGoalRequest ` code

Comment: @ABDEL-RHMAN - I have done that. I added the models and toreAppraisalGoalRequest